# Merging three factors so their dependent variable sums in R

Tags: r

Not sure if someone has answered this - I have searched, but so far nothing has worked for me. I have a very large dataset that I am trying to narrow. I need to combine three factors in my `"PROG"` variable `("Grad.2","Grad.3","Grad.H")` so that they become a single variable (`"Grad"`) where the dependent variable (`"NUMBER"`) of each comparable set of values is summed.

ie.

```
YEAR = "92/93"    AGE = "20-24"   PROG = "Grad.2"   NUMBER = "50"

YEAR = "92/93"    AGE = "20-24"   PROG = "Grad.3"   NUMBER = "25"

YEAR = "92/93"    AGE = "20-24"   PROG = "Grad.H"   NUMBER = "2"
```

turns into

```
YEAR = "92/93"    AGE = "20-24"   PROG = "Grad"   NUMBER = "77"
```

I want to then drop all other factors for `PROG` so that I can compare the enrollment rates for Grad without worrying about the other factors (which I deal with separately). So my active independent variables are `YEAR` and `AGE`, while the dependent variable is `NUMBER`.

I hope this shows my data adequately:

```
structure(list
(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("92/93", "93/94", "94/95", "95/96", "96/97", 
    "97/98", "98/99", "99/00", "00/01", "01/02", "02/03", "03/04", 
    "04/05", "05/06", "06/07", "07/08", "08/09", "09/10", "10/11", 
    "11/12", "12/13", "13/14", "14/15", "15/16"), class = "factor"), 
AGE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1-19", 
            "20-24", "25-30", "31-34", "35-39", "40+", "NR", "T.Age"), class = c("ordered", 
            "factor")), 
PROG = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("T.Prog", "Basic", "Career", "Grad.H", 
                "Grad2", "Grad3", "Grad2.Qual", "Grad3.Qual", "Health.Res", 
                "NoProg.Grad", "NoProg.Other", "NoProg.Und.Grad", "NoProg.NoCred", 
                "Other", "Post.Und.Grad", "Post.Career", "Pre-U", "Career.Qual", 
                "Und.Grad", "Und.Grad.Qual"), class = "factor"), 
NUMBER = c(104997L, 
                347235L, 112644L, 38838L, 35949L, 50598L, 5484L, 104991L, 
                333807L, 76692L)), row.names = c(7936L, 7948L, 7960L, 7972L, 
            7984L, 7996L, 8008L, 10459L, 10471L, 10483L), class = "data.frame")
```

In terms of why I am using factors, I don't know how else I should enter the data. Factors made sense, and they were how R interpreted the raw data when I uploaded it.

I am working on the suggestions below. Not had success yet, but I am still learning how to get R to do what I want, and frequently mess up. Will respond to each of you as soon as I have a reasonable answer to give. (And once I stop banging my poor head on my desk... sigh)

Comment: Welcome to SO. To add dataset load it in R and do something like `dput(head(data, 10))`. Where `data` is the name of your data.frame. Finally paste it here with appropriate formatting.

Comment: Also your expected output is not entirely clear. Do you want to merge many observations into one?

Comment: why are you using `factors` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it. 
I am assuming your data frame is named `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
mutate(PROG = ifelse(PROG %in% c("Grad2", "Grad3","Grad.H"), 
                     "Grad",
                     NA)) %>% ##combines the 3 Grad variables into one
filter(!is.na(PROG)) %>%     ##drops the other variables
group_by(YEAR, AGE) %>%      
summarise(NUMBER = sum(NUMBER))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate the way you explained what each step meant. Unfortunately I got the following error:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical".

Comment: I edited my comment, there was a paretheses lacking.

Comment: Also changed "Grad.2" and "Grad.3" to "Grad2" and "Grad3" so it matched your example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach: only take factors you want, drop the factor variable (because you want to treat them as a group) and sum up all `NUMBER` values while grouping by all other variables. `df` is your data.

```
aggregate(formula = NUMBER ~ .,
          data = subset(df, PROG %in% c("Grad2", "Grad3", "Grad.H"), select = -PROG),
          FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the levels() function is what you are looking for. From the manual:

```
## combine some levels
z <- gl(3, 2, 12, labels = c("apple", "salad", "orange"))
z
levels(z) <- c("fruit", "veg", "fruit")
z
```

I named your data temp and ran this code. It works for me.

```
z<-gl(n=length(temp$PROG),k=2,labels=c("T.Prog", "Basic", "Career", "Grad.H", 
            "Grad2", "Grad3", "Grad2.Qual", "Grad3.Qual", "Health.Res", 
            "NoProg.Grad", "NoProg.Other", "NoProg.Und.Grad", "NoProg.NoCred", 
            "Other", "Post.Und.Grad", "Post.Career", "Pre-U", "Career.Qual", 
            "Und.Grad", "Und.Grad.Qual"))
z
levels(z)<-c(rep("Other",3),rep("Grad",5),rep("Other",12))
z
temp$PROG2<-factor(x=temp$PROG,levels=levels(temp$PROG),labels=z)
temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to relabel the levels, but I just ended up with 3 instances of the data I was aiming for, rather than having them add together. Not sure if that was what you were suggesting, but that's what I am guessing. (Sorry, not very good at R yet.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You should try reading the manual carefully and recreating the examples at the end of the manual using your data.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I agree with FScott that you are likely looking for the levels() function to rename the factor levels. Here is how I would do the second step of summing.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

#do the renaming of the PROG variables here

#sum by PROG
df <- df %>%
   group_by(PROG) %>%  # you could add more variable names here to group by i.e. group_by(PROG, AGE, YEAR)
   mutate(group.sum= sum(NUMBER))
```

This chunk will make a new column in df named `group.sum` with the sum between subsetted groups defined by the `group_by()` function

if you wanted to condense the data.frame further as where the individual values in `NUMBER` are replaced with group.sum, again there are many ways to do this but here is a simple way.

```
#condense df down
df$number <- df$group.sum
df <- df[,-ncol(df)]
df <- unique(df)
```

A side note: I wouldn't recommend doing the above chunk because you loose information in your data, and your data is more tidy just having the extra column `group.sum`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried your code, but the group.sum ended up adding everything together, as far as I could tell. Not enough room to post the result here, sorry.